# UIStackView not visible

Tags: ios, swift

I have stackview in my Swift code

```
let comment1 = Comment(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
let comment2 = Comment(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
let comment3 = Comment(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 200, width: 100, height: 100))

let stackView = UIStackView()
stackView.axis  = UILayoutConstraintAxis.vertical
stackView.distribution  = UIStackViewDistribution.equalSpacing
stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.center
stackView.spacing   = 16.0
stackView.backgroundColor = .green
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

stackView.addArrangedSubview(comment1)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(comment2)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(comment3)

view.addSubview(stackView)

stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

`Comment`  is a subclass of UIView.The problem is that the stackView nor the subviews are visible.Why is that?

Comment: Hello, where did yo u add your stack view excatly?

Comment: @MohammadBashirSidani Right after the last `addArrangedSubview `

Comment: are you calling `self.view.addSubview(stackView)` ?

Comment: @saroshmirza yes i am

Comment: Why are you setting the frame of the Comments when you are adding them to the stack view? Why no just use constraints?

Comment: @sakoaskoaso, i added the answer below, did it help? if it did can you kindly accept it as a correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Just tested with your code. There seems to be the problem with your constraints. I added the constraints for heightAnchor and widthAchor which resulted in showing the stackView, before it was not visible.
below is the code and also the image attached.

Note: since i didn't had Comment view so i used simply UIView. You will need to change it back to Comment

```
let comment1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
let comment2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
let comment3 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 200, width: 100, height: 100))

comment1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
comment1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true

comment2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
comment2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true

comment3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
comment3.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true

comment1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
comment2.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
comment3.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

let stackView = UIStackView()
stackView.axis  = UILayoutConstraintAxis.vertical
stackView.distribution  = UIStackViewDistribution.equalSpacing
stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.center
stackView.spacing   = 16.0
stackView.backgroundColor = .green
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

stackView.addArrangedSubview(comment1)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(comment2)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(comment3)


self.view.addSubview(stackView)


stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

[image]